# Netbeans topcomponent initComponents

Tags: java, netbeans, constructor, components, size

I have a topComponent's constructor like this:

```
public BrowserTopComponent()
{
    initComponents();
    System.out.println("TopComponent size: "+this.getSize());
    System.out.println("TopComponnet prefered size: "+this.getSize());
    setName(NbBundle.getMessage(BrowserTopComponent.class,
                                "CTL_BrowserTopComponent"));
    setToolTipText(NbBundle.getMessage(BrowserTopComponent.class,
                                       "HINT_BrowserTopComponent"));

    System.out.println("JPanel size: "+jPanel1.getSize());
    System.out.println("JScrollPane1 size: "+jScrollPane1.getSize());

    //  setIcon(ImageUtilities.loadImage(ICON_PATH, true));

}
```

The problem is with all getSize() calls on components. They all return [width=0, height=0]. I don't understand when getSize() is initialized, to get right sizes? How can I get actually sizes of my components in constructor?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this.getPrefferedSize().width & this.getPrefferedSize().length  instead. This will return to you the preferred (or actual) dimensions of the component.